# .proj file to read and update data in .json file

Tags: json, configuration, msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm writing a build.proj file to build and deploy a application. I have one **application.configuration** file which contains some project configurations. **application.configuration** is written in json format.

```
{
  "Clients": [
    {
      "Id": "xyz",
      "Name": "test",
      "Flow": "2"
    }
  ],
  "Scopes": [
    {
      "Name": "roles",
      "DisplayName": "roles",
      "Claims": [
        {
          "Name": "role"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In build.proj file a want to **read and update data** from this file so what should i use?

Because MSBUILD Tasks only reads and update data from .xml files.

Comment: Have you tried something? Basically you'd select your tool of choice and use it in msbuild; the *MSBUILD Tasks only reads and update data from .xml files* is only half the truth: you know you can easily write custom tasks using .net code? Or invoke Powershell? Or ... ?

Comment: I'm trying JsonPoke and JsonPeek build tasks 1.0.7.